# Why does conversion from DATETIME to DATETIME2 appear to change value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I had a stored procedure comparing two dates. From the logic of my application, I expected them to be equal. However, the comparison failed. The reason for this was the fact that one of the values was stored as a `DATETIME` and had to be `CONVERT`-ed to a `DATETIME2` before being compared to the other `DATETIME2`. Apparently, this changed its value. I have run this little test:

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME='2018-01-18 16:12:25.113'
DECLARE @DateTime2 DATETIME2='2018-01-18 16:12:25.1130000'
SELECT @DateTime, @DateTime2, DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, @DateTime, @DateTime2)
```

Which gave me the following result:
[image: -333333ns difference]

Why is there the difference of 333333ns between these values? I thought that a `DATETIME2`, as a more precise type, should be able to accurately represent all the values which can be stored in a `DATETIME`? [The documentation of DATETIME2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) only says:

> When the conversion is from datetime, the date and time are copied. The fractional precision is extended to 7 digits.

No warnings about the conversion adding or subtracting 333333ns to or from the value! So why does this happen?

I am using SQL Server 2016.

**edit:** Strangely, on a different server I am getting a zero difference. Both are SQL Server 2016 but the one where I have the problem has compatibility level set to 130, the one where I don't has it set to 120. Switching between them changes this behaviour.

**edit2:** DavidG suggested in the comments that the value I am using can be represented as a `DATETIME2` but not a `DATETIME`. So I have modified my test to make sure that the value I am assigning to `@DateTime2` is a valid `DATETIME` value:

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME='2018-01-18 16:12:25.113'
DECLARE @DateTime2 DATETIME2=CONVERT(DATETIME2, @DateTime)
SELECT @DateTime, @DateTime2, DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, @DateTime, @DateTime2)
```

This helps a little because the difference is smaller but still not zero:
[image: -33ns difference]

Comment: It's floating point precision. The value of `2018-01-18 16:12:25.113` is impossible to represent in a `datetime` value.

Comment: I am using sql server 2014, I can't reproduce; I get `0` from datediff.

Comment: @HoneyBadger See my edit about compatibility levels.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A [breaking change](http://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-2016-and-azure-sql-database-v12-breaking-change/) was introduced in SQL Server 2016 with regards to conversion and comparison of datetime and datetime2. The changes are detailed in [this knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4010261/sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-improvements-in-handling-some-data-t).

In summary, values were rounded during the conversion in SQL 2014 and earlier versions whereas the full precision is considered nowadays. This improves performance but introduces issues when converting and comparing these unlike types.

Comment: Thank you, I need to read it more carefully but this article seems to describe precisely the issue I am experiencing. And it explains why lowering the compatibility level helps.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/), `DATETIME` precision is .00333 seconds, while `DATETIME2` (or `DATETIME2(7)` explicitly) has 100 ns precision. So even comparing `DATETIME` to `DATETIME2(3)`, which would seem to have the same precision, `DATETIME2(3)` is more precise.

This weird 3.33 ms precision of `DATETIME` is the reason why when comparing seemingly equal values, you *can* get a difference.

Answer (score 4):

`datetime2` is shorthand for `datetime2(7)`, which indicates you want 7 digits for fractional seconds (the maximum).  Try a `datetime2(3)` if you want something closer to a `datetime`.

Also, be aware that `datetime2(3)` is more precise than a `datetime`.  The latter rounds to the nearest 0.000, 0.003, or 0.007 by design.

Answer (score 2):

To me, when you do comparison, you actually should convert data with high precision to low precision to avoid such "difference"

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME='2018-01-18 16:12:25.113'
DECLARE @DateTime2 DATETIME2='2018-01-18 16:12:25.1130000'
SELECT @DateTime, cast(@DateTime2 as datetime), DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, @DateTime, cast(@DateTime2 as datetime))
```

The result is

[image]